# Laravel Nova BelongsTo Field Appending Namespace To Current Namespace

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-nova

I am currently using laravel 5.8 with laravel nova.

When i use a model class inside my nova action file, like this:

```
Namespace App\Nova\Actions;

use App\Nova\User;
use Orlyapps\NovaBelongsToDepend\NovaBelongsToDepend;

class PlayerDD extends Action
{

    public $name = 'Spelers toekennen';

    /**
     * Perform the action on the given models.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Fields\ActionFields  $fields
     * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection  $models
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Get the fields available on the action.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields()
    {        
        return [
            BelongsTo::make(User::class)
        ];
    }
}
```

Laravel returns the error: *Class 'App\Nova\Actions\App\Nova\User' not found.*

While i am using the root namespace for the **User model**, the namespace gets appended to the current namespace.

Is there a fix for this, and where should i look for conflicts?

Thanks in advance!

BTW, i tried this \App\Nova\User

Comment: What namespace is your PlayerDD class in? I'm not 100% sure if this is correct, but I think if your class is not namespaced, then the full namespace of your use statement will be whatever directory your PlayerDD class is in.

Comment: I forgot to add this in my code above. Apologies

Comment: I think the BelongsTo field can't be used inside a Nova Action to quote this "Nova allows you to attach most of Nova's supported fields directly to an action"

Comment: I was wrong other fields dont work either

Comment: They have labeled this as a bug, the answer maybe given here https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/2183#issuecomment-561133279